# Make relation between two different arrays in a loop

Tags: arrays, bash, loops, multidimensional-array, indexing

I created two arrays:

1st array:

```
echo "${array1[@]}"
two
three
four
five
```

2nd array:

```
echo "${array2[@]}"
apples
carrots
potatoes
tomatoes
```

I would like to combine them inside a loop (or something similar) and to keep relations between the first array and the second one.

```
two apples
three carrots
four potatoes
five tomatoes
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To zip two parallel arrays, iterate over the indices. (This assumes that both arrays use the same indices, which is almost always the case.)

```
for i in "${!array1[@]}"; do
  new_array+=( "${array1[i]} ${array2[i]}" )
done
```

Comment: Thank you so much chepner this worked well!